# query hangs oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring, jdbc

I have this strange issue with our software.
Is is on production for 5 years and we had no such problems...

Problem:

We have a spring job (scheduler) which makes a query via hibernate, retrieves the objects and modifies them.

Well, this worked for several years but a month ago the query hangs 5-10 times a day (the query is invoked every 10 minutes). And when it hangs, we have to restart the service.

The following code does the query:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Delivery> findScheduledForDelivery(final String inType, final int max, final String benefitType ) {


    //getHibernateTemplate().clear();

    return getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws SQLException {
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Delivery.class);

            criteria.createAlias("reward","r");
            criteria.createAlias("r.customer","c");
            criteria.createAlias("c.inNe","i");
            criteria.createAlias("r.promotion","p");
            criteria.createAlias("benefit","b");

            String sqlCustAlias = StringHelper.generateAlias("c", 2);

            criteria.add(Expression.disjunction()
                .add(Expression.eq("inStatus", INStatus.InterfaceFailure))
                .add(Expression.eq("inStatus",INStatus.Initial)));

            criteria.add(Expression.le("deliverAt", new Date()));

            String dateString = "2000/01/01";
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            Date startDate = new Date();
            try {
                startDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
                criteria.add(Expression.ge("deliverAt", startDate));
            }
            catch(ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String sqlEqual = "decode(delivered,null,0,1) = 0";
            criteria.add(Expression.sql(sqlEqual));

            sqlEqual = "decode(" + sqlCustAlias + ".deleteDate,null,1,0) = 1";
            criteria.add(Expression.sql(sqlEqual));

            if(inType  != null ) {
                for(INType i : INType.values())
                    if(i.toString().equals(inType)) {
                        criteria.add(Expression.eq("i.inType", i));
                        break;
                    }
            }

            criteria.add(Expression.eq("p.active", true));

            if(benefitType != null) {
                if(benefitType.equals("FREECREDIT")) 
                    criteria.add(Expression.disjunction()
                            .add(Expression.eq("b.type", BenefitType.FREE_CREDIT))
                            .add(Expression.eq("b.type", BenefitType.FREE_CREDIT_FTAM)));
                else if(benefitType.equals("NONFREECREDIT")) {
                    criteria.add(Expression.conjunction()
                            .add(Expression.ne("b.type", BenefitType.FREE_CREDIT))
                            .add(Expression.ne("b.type", BenefitType.OTHER))
                            .add(Expression.ne("b.type", BenefitType.VOUCHER)));
                    criteria.add(Expression.isNull("b.md3Profile")); 
                }
                if(max != 0)
                    criteria.setMaxResults(max);
            }

            criteria.addOrder( Order.desc("p.priority") );
            criteria.addOrder( Order.asc("deliverAt") );



            return criteria.list(); <===== hangs here
        }
    });
}
```

Data source is defined as this (I know that this is not supposed to be on production but this is the only way it works - I tried to use oracle connection pool but then the query hangs more often..):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
    <beans>
      <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="connectionProperties">
         <props>
          <prop key="tcp.nodelay">yes</prop>
          <prop key="delayRowPrefetch">20</prop>
          <prop key="defaultBatchSize">5</prop>
         </props>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </beans>
```

Software used:

- spring 1.2.7
- hibernate 3.0.5
- oracle 10.2.0.1 (RAC)
- oracle jdbc 10.1.0.2
- Red Hat 3 EL
- Java 1.5_06

What I've tried so far:

- use oracle connection pool as data
  source -> failed with hanging
  connections
- used oracle jdbc 10.2.0.5 -> I thought I've solved it ... and after a few hours it hanged again :(

There are no database locks on oracle as far I can see...

What could be the problem?

## UPDATE:

in oracle EM:

ADDM findings:
SQL statements consuming significant database time were found.
The query consumes significant database time. Impact 81%.
User I/O waits 97%.

- Individual SQL statements responsible
  for significant user I/O wait were
  found.
- Individual database segments
  responsible for significant user I/O
  wait were found.
- The throughput of the I/O subsystem
  was significantly lower than
  expected.

## UPDATE: (15.03.2011)

For now the service works for almost 48 hours without hanging.

I'm skeptical that this will solve the problem but I did some changes to the code:

Removed the `decode(delivered,null,0,1) = 0` and `decode(" + sqlCustAlias + ".deleteDate,null,1,0) = 1` functions in query and replaced them with `is null` statements.
The delivered field is indexed but indexing can't be used in `decode` functions.

Do you think that this is just coincidence?

## UPDATE: (16.03.2011)

alert.log now shows many entries like this:

```
ORA-01555 caused by SQL statement below (SQL ID: affkpm4j7azc4, Query Duration=232624 sec, SCN: 0x0003.dca70559):
Tue Mar 15 17:43:06 2011
select * from ( select this_.id as id5_, this_.deliverAt as deliverAt68_5_, this_.delivered as delivered68_5_, this_.inDelivery as inDelivery68_5_, this_.lastDeliveryTry as lastDeli5_68_5_, this_.tries as tries68_5_, this_.sentAt as sentAt68_5_, this_.sent as sent68_5_, this_.retry as retry68_5_, this_.inStatus as inStatus68_5_, this_.errorMessage as errorMe11_68_5_, this_.inCvsDelivery as inCvsDe12_68_5_, this_.cvsDelivered as cvsDeli13_68_5_, this_.cvsLastDeliveryTry as cvsLast14_68_5_, this_.cvsTries as cvsTries68_5_, this_.collectedPoints as collect16_68_5_, this_.smsMessage as smsMessage68_5_, this_.inOldStatus as inOldSt18_68_5_, this_.replacedDate as replace19_68_5_, this_.oldMsisdn as oldMsisdn68_5_, this_.deletedDate as deleted21_68_5_, this_.addManualDate as addManu22_68_5_, this_.stornoPromiseDate as stornoP23_68_5_, this_.stornoINDate as stornoI24_68_5_, this_.activationCode as activat25_68_5_, this_.activationExpirationDate as activat26_68_5_, this_.rewardId as rewardId68_5_, this_.benefitId as b
```

It seems to be from sessions 3 days before.. 232624seconds!

Comment: +1 because you're obviously working on the weekend to solve a production issue. There's no overtime in our profession, but at least there's a couple rep :-)

Comment: thank you very much. Weekends are reserved for EMCYs :-)

Comment: My experience has been that if something was working, but now it isn't, it's only because something changed. This code hasn't changed, which means your data probably has. Now, I know about as much about hibernate as that rock over there, so I can't analyze the code to find the problem very well, but I would look at what might have changed with the data. Of course, you've been over that already I'm sure... but *shrug* just worth mentioning.

Comment: Do you mean that you are restarting the Oracle service every time this query hangs?  Is it causing other sessions to hang?

Comment: When the query runs successfully how long does it take?

Comment: @Dave Costa No, just our java application/process. We have 8 java applications which are connected to oracle. And only this one is causing problems so we have to restart it...

Comment: @Alohci mostly about 200ms. When problems begin then the query takes from 10s to even 1 minute and then the hanging begins.

Comment: @alesko - Did you get a resolution to this? A java app slowing down, then stopping is often indicative of it running out of memory. Do you have access to the heap usage or garbage collection stats?

Comment: @Alohci Memory is ok. gc.log shows only 200MB used. -Xmx is set to 2048M

Comment: You say "the query" is executed every 10 minutes, but the method shown is capable of creating and executing a number of different queries.  Is it called every 10 minutes with the same parameters?  If so, what are they?  If it is called with different parameters, is there any relationship between the parameters passed and whether the query hangs?

Comment: @Dave Costa The parameter benefitType is either FREECREDIT or NONFREECREDIT. I can say for sure that the parameter will never be null. Hanging occures for both benefitsTypes. But also I noticed sometimes that only FREECREDIT hangs and and the other works but after a few hours also the query with the other benefitType hangs.

Comment: Out of curiousity, did you ever solve this? We recently had a hibernate query do basically the same thing, and I found this on Google. Then I saw the first comment and though 'wow that sounds like something I'd say!'... and, well, yeah...

Comment: We actually never found out. As far as I remember we restarted the cluster and since then it thankfully works...

Answer (score 3):

First thing, when this query hangs, check V$SESSION_WAIT to see what the session is waiting on.

Second observation:  The code you've shown above appears to ignore the `max` parameter unless the `benefitType` parameter is non-null.  Is this intentional?  Is it possible that the query is "hanging" only when the benefitType parameter is null?

Sorry, I assumed you had some way of identifying the correct session within Oracle.  Try a query like this:

```
select v2.sid,
       v2.module,
       substr(v1.sql_text,1,180) sql_text,
       v1.rows_processed,
       v2.event,
       v2.seq#
from v$sqlarea v1, v$session v2
where v1.users_executing > 0
  and v2.sql_address (+) = v1.address;
```

That will show all the SQL currently being executed, and if possible the related session ID and what event it is waiting on.  You should be able to use the SQL text to identify the session you are interested in.

Comment: I will check it as soon as it happens again. This shouldn't take long.

Comment: And to be clear, check a few times and see if the wait event changes or the sequence number changes.  Even if it's waiting on the same event but the sequence number changes, that means it's doing work, just very slowly.

Comment: The question is how to find out which session is the one which is hanging? There are 16+ sessions with event "SQL*Net message from/to client".

Comment: sorry can't find anything suspicious in session_wait. Maybe the client couldn't obtain a connection to oracle so we can't see it.

Comment: "SQL*Net message from/to client" usually means the database session is idle.